# Read a Xcode Instruments .trace file generated from Automation.tracetemplate

Tags: xcode, instruments, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I need to read/parse instruments trace file generated using Automation.tracetemplate. Is there any command line utility or anything that can read the file without opening instruments.

I am running an automation script on an iOS application using instrument command from the command line which generates aan instruments trace file as an output result. Now i need to read/parse this file without opening instruments so that i can have a readable data to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the UIAutomation trace file, parsing the data is very simple. Instead of looking at the **"1.run"** file generated inside the **Instruments.trace** file; look inside the "**Automation Results.plist**" file. That's just XML so you can easily write a parser for it.